# SAS - Can't get code to work when put into a macro (remote server)

Tags: sas

I have a block of code that connects to a remote server, passes a few variables to it, and then queries data on the server and then manipulates it.  This code works exactly as I would expect it, producing the data I need.

However, I need to run the code in a macro loop.  This is where it all breaks down.  I'm not sure what the issue is, but I suspect it is some sort of variable scope problem.  I have tried to research doing this online, but cannot figure it out.

The problem occurs in the `data xtemp2` block.  When I try to run this, I get the following errors:

```
WARNING: Apparent symbolic reference INTERVAL_SECONDS not resolved.
ERROR 22-322: Syntax error, expecting one of the following: a name,
              a quoted string, a numeric constant, a datetime constant,
              a missing value, INPUT, PUT.
```

and

```
WARNING: Apparent symbolic reference START_TIME not resolved.
ERROR 22-322: Syntax error, expecting one of the following: a name,
              a quoted string, a numeric constant, a datetime constant,
              a missing value, INPUT, PUT.
```

Please also note that I sometimes get similar errors with `rtime`, `iprice`, `oprice`, and `itime`.  Once again, this code works perfectly well when I run it by itself.  Putting it into a macro with a loop seems to generate these problems, which makes me think I am not initializing these variables properly.  I would really appreciate any insight and tips you could provide.

```
%macro getthedata(nrows,ystart,yend); *nrows is the number of rows in the text file;
    %do i=1 %to &nrows;
        %do m=&ystart %to &yend;

            (...)
            signon username=_prompt_;
            %syslput VAR1 = &var1;
            %syslput M = &m;

            rsubmit;
            libname abc'/data/sasdata'; *Thisis where the datasets are located; 
            %let start_time = '9:30:00't; * starting time;
            %let interval_seconds =15*60; * interval is 15*60 seconds, 15min;

            data all2009;
                set sas.a_&M.01:; 
                by symbol date time;
                where symbol = &VAR1 and time between '9:30:00't and '16:00:00't;
            run;

            data xtemp2;
                set all2009;
                by symbol date time;
                format itime rtime time12.;
                if first.symbol=1 or first.date=1 then do;
                    *Initialize time and price when new symbol or date starts;
                    rtime=time;
                    iprice=bid;
                    oprice=ofr;
                    itime=&start_time;
                end;
                if time >= itime then do; *Intervalreached;
                    output; *rtime and iprice hold the last observation values;
                    itime = itime +&interval_seconds;
                    do while(time >= itime); *need to fill in alltime intervals;
                        output;
                        itime = itime +&interval_seconds;
                    end;
                end;
                rtime=time;
                iprice=bid;
                oprice=ofr;
                retain itime rtime iprice oprice; *Carry time and price valuesforward;
                *keep symbol date itime iprice rtime;
            run;

            proc download data=all2009 out=local.all30 (keep=SYMBOL DATE PRICE SIZE itime);
            run;

            endrsubmit;
            (...)
         %end;
    %end;
%mend getthedata;

Options MPRINT;

%getthedata(3,2007,2007)
```

**SOLUTION** (per Joe's Answer)

I was able to successfully create the `interval_seconds` and `start_time` variables using the `%NRSTR` solution Joe posted.

Here is the relevant modified code section:

```
(...)
            signon username=_prompt_;
            %syslput VAR1 = &var1;
            %syslput M = &m;
            rsubmit;
            libname abc'/data/sasdata'; *Thisis where the datasets are located; 
            %nrstr(%%)let start_time = '9:30:00't; * CHANGED LINE;
            %nrstr(%%)let interval_seconds =15*60; * CHANGED LINE;
            data all2009;
                set sas.a_&M.01:; 
                by symbol date time;
                where symbol = &VAR1 and time between '9:30:00't and '16:00:00't;
            run;
(...)
```

Comment: There isn't a scoping issue with what you show.  Inside the RSUBMIT, there is no macro being run, so there's no scope issue - it's a global variable.  Unless you're not telling us something about the &interval_seconds, there's no reason I see why that should be occurring.

Comment: I would add that this is probably not a good solution to your overall problem.  You could solve the problem without a macro loop, and in particular without rsubmitting repeatedly; this seems solveable with a properly constructed larger data set and BY statements, which would be likely an order or two of magnitude more efficient if you're running loops repeatedly.

Comment: The reason I'm looping like this is that I want to pull a small subset of the data at a time (where "small" is still hundreds of MBs).  Can you please shed more light as to what the actual error means?  Is it saying that the variable is blank?

Comment: You're pulling several small subsets, though.  Pull them all at once in one pull, give them an arbitrary coding variable (say, `pull=1;`) and then perform whatever analysis you're doing `by pull;`.  Or even pull all your data down at once and then subset it locally just before needing to, if you really can't use `by`.  Either way, much more efficient than a bunch of RSUBMITs in a macro loop.  (Also, you don't need to `signon;` once per loop- one signon for the entire program should work if you are careful about dataset names and macro variables.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can give you a functional solution, but I haven't figured out the whys yet.

Basically, the %let statements (and %put statements) are being ignored.  They're not being passed down - in fact they're being executed on the local machine.  See this:

```
%let var1="Region1";
signon;
libname uwork slibref=work server=unix;
data uwork.pricedata;
set sashelp.pricedata;
run;

%macro getthedata(nrows,ystart,yend); *nrows is the number of rows in the text file;
    %do i=1 %to &nrows;
        %do m=&ystart %to &yend;
            signon;
            %syslput VAR1 = &var1;
            %syslput ystart=&ystart;
            %syslput yend=&yend;
            %syslput start_time='01JAN1998'd;
            %syslput interval_seconds=30;
            rsubmit;
            %*libname abc '/data/sasdata'; *Thisis where the datasets are located; 

            %let start_time = '01JAN1998'd; * starting time;  *these are ignored by the rsubmit - why?;
            %let interval_seconds =30; * interval is 15*60 seconds, 15min;

            %put &start_time &interval_seconds;
            data all2009;
                set work.pricedata; 
                by date;
                where year(date) ge &ystart. and year(date) le &yend.;
            run;

            data xtemp2;
                set all2009;
                by date;
                format itime rtime time12.;
                if first.date=1 then do;
                    *Initialize time and price when new symbol or date starts;
                    rtime=date;
                    iprice=price;
                    oprice=cost;
                    itime=&start_time;
                end;
                if date >= itime then do; *Intervalreached;
                    output; *rtime and iprice hold the last observation values;
                    itime = itime +&interval_seconds;
                    do while(date >= itime); *need to fill in alltime intervals;
                        output;
                        itime = itime +&interval_seconds;
                    end;
                end;
                rtime=date;
                iprice=price;
                oprice=discount;
                retain itime rtime iprice oprice; *Carry time and price valuesforward;
                *keep symbol date itime iprice rtime;
            run;

            /*proc download data=all2009 out=local.all30 (keep=SYMBOL DATE PRICE SIZE itime);
            run;
*/
            endrsubmit;
            %put &start_time &interval_seconds;
         %end;
    %end;
%mend getthedata;

Options MPRINT;
%getthedata(3,1998,1998)
```

Notice that the %put statement at the end, after the endrsubmit, actually works - even though it shouldn't (the macro variables shouldn't be defined on the local machine).  There must be some issue with RSUBMITs inside of macros having macro variables, and there I have no real answers other than %SYSLPUTting it before you rsubmit (hence why my example works).

You could consider moving the RSUBMIT code to a remote batch program that you execute rather than RSUBMITting, perhaps, or even %include- maybe that would get around it (ie, inside the RSUBMIT have an %include that is referring to a remote program).

Take a look at [this SAS article](http://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/connref/61908/HTML/default/viewer.htm#a001584568.htm), which gives you some explanation of what's happening (basically what I said is in fact the case) and how to work around it.  `SYSLPUT` is the first suggestion, and using other workarounds like `%NRSTR` also are possibilities.

Comment: Wow, thank you so much.  I'll take a look at this now and comment back if I have more questions.  Thanks again!

Comment: In the article you linked, is the `SYSLPUT` solution they offer the same thing you demonstrated in the code above?  That doesn't really work, right?

Comment: I was able to successfully create the `interval_seconds` and `start_time` variables using the `%NRSTR` solution you posted.  However, now I have a different problem involving 'itime'.  It appears as though the variables is never created.  I put more detail in my original post...

Comment: Wow, you're totally right.  I just changed it and it works perfectly!  Thanks so much!

Answer (score 1):

The code looks like it should run, but I've tried something similar and had same problem.
You create local macro so the macro statements like LET are executed locally. While datastep statements are executed by remote SAS.
The solution is to define macro in remote session.

See effect of where is macro compiled below:

1) local macro:

```
%macro local_macro;
    rsubmit;
        %put %sysget(COMPUTERNAME);
    endrsubmit;
%mend;

%local_macro
```

2) remote macro

```
rsubmit;
    %macro remote_macro;
        %put %sysget(COMPUTERNAME);
    %mend;
endrsubmit;

rsubmit;
%remote_macro
;
endrsubmit;
```

Comment: Depending on what are you trying to develop in general, first thing you should decide is are you in fact coding for server (remote session) or for local SAS with some tasks running on remote. In 99% of cases I'm using local SAS just as an editor and write and run all code for server. For this, I've defined a F12 key as "rsubmit" and run all code via F12 key, instead of F8. Thus I don't need to write RSUBMIT and ENDRSUBMITs. Press F9 to see key definitions.

Comment: I'd add that comment to the answer, it's a more complete answer than the rest of the answer ;)